# Add waves in after effects

Tags: effects, 3d, shape

How do I create waves that follows the users motion like this[image: dance]
Anything in this direction is appreciated except don't tell me to draw

Answer (score 0):

You could track points on the arms to control the motion of a shape layer with a row of points or short strokes on it, then apply the **echo** effect. How well that would work would depend on the speed the arms move.

You could also apply the tracking to some nulls, and copy their motion paths onto a shape layer's path property, or the path property of a write-on effect.

Comment: Is there a plugin to make a rope unattatched at one end

Comment: If you have additional questions you should ask them as a separate question, rather than in the comments. You might want to take a minute to read the FAQ for this site.